# Understanding map in Scala

Tags: scala

Please help me understand what map(_(0)) means here:

```
scala> a.collect
res97: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1039], [1010], [1002], [926])

scala> a.collect.map(_(0))
res98: Array[Any] = Array(1039, 1010, 1002, 926)
```

Comment: Read some books instead of dumping a "what this means" question every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. `.map` in functional programming applies the function you want to each element of your collection.**

Say, you want to add some data to each element in an array you have, which can be done as below,

```
scala> val data = Array("a", "b", "c")
data: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> data.map(element => element+"-add something")
res10: Array[String] = Array(a-add something, b-add something, c-add something)
```

Here, I'm saying, on each element `add something`, but `element` is unnecessary because you are adding on `every element` anyway. So, `_` is what represents **any element** here.

So, same map can be done in following way.

```
scala> data.map(_+"-add something")
res9: Array[String] = Array(a-add something, b-add something, c-add something)
```

Also, note that `_` is used when you have one line mapping function.

**2. `collection(index)` is the way to access nth element in a collection.**

eg.

```
scala> val collection = Array(Vector(1039), Vector(1010), Vector(1002), Vector(926))
collection: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] = Array(Vector(1039), Vector(1010), Vector(1002), Vector(926))

scala> collection(0)
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1039)
```

So, combining #1 and #2, in your case you are mapping the original collection and getting the first element.

```
scala> collection.map(_.head)
res17: Array[Int] = Array(1039, 1010, 1002, 926)
```

### Refs

https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#map

[Map, Map and flatMap in Scala](http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the zeroth element of the items in the collection `a`. `_` is a common placeholder in Scala when working with the items in a collection.

More concretely, your code is equivalent to

```
a.collect.map(item => item(0))
```